# Logback 1.3.0 and Jetty 9.4.50 having the compatibility issues

Tags: java, jetty, logback, logback-classic, end-of-life

Logaback version 1.3.0 uses Javax-Servlet version 4.0.1.

In the same application, I am using Jetty 9.4.50, which uses javax-servlet 3.1.0.

When I load logback.xml locally, my application works successfully.

If I start the application through the Jetty server, no logs are generated

( logback.xml file cannot be loaded by the Jetty server).

According to my understanding, Logback and Jetty have the same Javax-servlet version

Could you please tell me why my logs are not generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, and most important, Jetty 9.x is now at End of Community Support.

See announcement at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/7958

You should be using Jetty 10+ now.

For Logback, you cannot use Logback 1.3.x on Jetty 9.x

That's because it requires Servlet 4.0.1, which is available on Jetty 10+ (not Jetty 9)

For Jetty 9.x you should stick with Logback 1.2.x, but that also means you are stuck with [all of the Hanging / Blocked Thread / Async / 100% CPU bugs](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues?q=is%3Aissue+logback) that logback hasn't fixed in Logback 1.2.x (many were fixed in Logback 1.3.x, and a lot more were fixed in Logback 1.4.x).

The breakdown of Logback to Servlet to Jetty

| Logback | Servlet | Namespace | Jetty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.2.x | Servlet 3.1.x | `javax.servlet` | Jetty 9.x |
| 1.3.x | Servlet 4.0.x | `javax.servlet` | Jetty 10.x |
| 1.4.x | Servlet 5.0.x | `jakarta.servlet` | Jetty 11.x |

Comment: Yes, I have been stuck in this situation for the past few weeks, and my analysis has been the same as well.